# how to make a autorun schedule for program at certain interval in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, python, asp.net

i wrote a python program for webscraping for eg: WCfixture.py .i am making a asp.net application in C# so the output from python is stored as text and that text is stored in database which is shown in my application.So now i want to auto run the python program at certain interval so that its output can be updated.Can you suggest me how i can do it?if possible with some code example.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) can be used to schedule tasks.  It has a command line, GUI and API interface.

Answer (score 0):

To periodically send an HTTP request to my ASP.NET application, I use a PowerShell script like this:

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://my.app.com/api/maintenance/do-something")
$request.Method = "POST"
$response = $request.GetResponse()
$response.Close()
```

And a following command to schedule it as I like:

```
schtasks /Create /SC DAILY /ST 04:30 /MO 1 /TN MyTaskName /TR "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File c:\ScheduledTasks\doSomething.ps1"
```

This will make the request being sent every day at 4:30 AM.

See the [documentation of schtask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).